# I can't update my BIOS because the current version is an empty string

Tags: motherboard, bios, updates

I am using an Intel D945GCCR motherboard. I want to update the BIOS but the current installed BIOS has an empty string for the BIOS version which causes an error and prevents me updating.

The error is "**current bios version and update bios version does not match**".

Due to this error i am unable to update bios.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Is it failing to update (what is the error message) or are you unable to locate the correct version to download?

Comment: when i try to update my bios it says that your current bios version and update bios version does not match.

Comment: We know. You said it in your original question. I think @kez is getting at the fact you're not providing enough information...

Comment: i want to update my bios because the older version does not have many option like 1-enhanced intel speed step technology 2-Chipset-SATA 

IDE: Compatibility mode  AHCI support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs while board repairing. Who repair board has replaced an ic of someother board that's why the bios is not showing bios string.

Comment: So the entire BIOS flash IC had to be replaced... :(

Answer (score 4):

Look between the processor socket and DIMM slots and make sure it says Intel. If so:

Go [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&changeLang=true&DwnldID=16762) and grab either "CR94510J.86A.0060.EB.EXE" or "CR94510J.86A.0060.BI.ZIP". The latter one will have to be done from a usb. These should work. And make sure you already have the BIOS recovery tool before doing anything.

This is a known issue with your board going back at least 4 years (see [here](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=153198), [here](http://www.dexplor.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7748800) and [here](http://www.pcguide.com/vb/showthread.php?threadid=49386)). If you  still can't get it updated even with the proper files you might need to find some of the older versions of the BIOS and try doing the update from the command prompt without booting into windows.

Comment: i have download these bios update but when i start them then an error shows that ur current bios version and update version does not match. Actually these update first check the bios version so that no one accidentally update a wrong version. but i have an empty string in front of version so it does not match, that's why it throws an error.

Comment: This is why they have multiple methods. I added some more info and links above.

Comment: let me check these may be some one works

Answer (score 2):

The cause could be a power outage during a previous BIOS update (and if this is the cause, then you're really lucky that it works at all).

If the motherboard is under warranty, contact Intel for a replacement -- they'll also be able to assist you in determining if the motherboard is under warranty, which is sometimes longer than the computer's general warranty.

Intel - How to Obtain Warranty Support
  http://www.intel.com/support/replacements.htm

Comment: no my motherboard is about 4 or 5 years old. and i never update my bios. but once the  board has some problem and i got it repaired from the computer market. May be they have done some thing wrong

Comment: @iqbal khan:  Well, if the people at the computer market lost power during a BIOS update (many technicians update the BIOS when they service motherboards), then this is one possible cause as well.  It's too bad that it's so old, but do check with Intel anyway because I've had a few motherboards that had unusually long warranties.