# Motherboard BIOS version has an empty sting

Tags: windows, motherboard, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't update my BIOS because the current version is an empty string](https://superuser.com/questions/280713/i-cant-update-my-bios-because-the-current-version-is-an-empty-string)

I am using an Intel D945GCCR motherboard.  I want to update the BIOS but the current installed BIOS has an empty string for the BIOS version (in the pre-boot BIOS management interface) which results in an error and prevents me updating.

The error is "Current BIOS version and updated BIOS versions do not match."

I do not know how this string goes away but now I need to solve this problem.  I have not found any solution or any help.

I am re-asking this question on this same forum because I have not found any solutions.

---

check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/280713/i-cant-update-my-bios-because-the-current-version-is-an-empty-string) for Ans